# Grails: Error while passing params via oauth tag to controller

Tags: grails, oauth, scribe

I have following in my gsp:

```
<oauth:connect provider="facebook" params="[currentURL: location.protocol + '//'
            + location.host + location.pathname]">
    <img src="../images/socialSites/facebook.png" alt="facebook" />
</oauth:connect>
```

And following code in controller:

```
 def currentURL = params.currentURL
 println "currentURL is :"+currentURL;
```

and getting this error and page is not displayed:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'protocol' on null object
```

I read [here](http://aiten.github.io/grails-oauth-scribe/guide/usingThePlugin.html) that oauth can accept all params that g:link can accept, so trying to send current url to controller so as I can redirect to same page after login is successful. How do i make it happen?

Answer (score 1):

`location.protocol`/`location.host`/`location.pathname`/etc. would work in JavaScript, but inside the `params` map only Groovy is supported, and that code has no access to the client-side state. Use

```
params="[currentURL: request.scheme + '://' + request.serverName + ':' + request.serverPort + request.forwardURI]"
```

instead.

Comment: ok got that.. but tried what you said, and still when I see the source of html page, I see no params in link: <a href="/JewelPari_V3/oauth/facebook/authenticate" provider="facebook"><img src="../images/socialSites/facebook.png" alt="facebook" /></a>

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add `params` to the `connect` tab of `oauth taglib` because it is not adding given `params` to the `URL`.

To achieve your requirement create your custom tag for authentication:

```
class MyOauthTagLib {

  static namespace = 'o'

  def connect = { attrs, body ->
    String provider = attrs.provider
    Map params = attrs.remove('params')

    if (!provider) {
        throw new GrailsTagException('No provider specified for <o:connect /> tag. Try <o:connect provider="your-provider-name" />')
    }

    Map a = attrs + [url: [controller: 'oauth', action: 'authenticate', params: [provider: provider] + params]]
    out << g.link(a, body)
  }
}
```

and use it in your gsp:

```
<o:connect provider="facebook" params="[currentURL: request.scheme + '://' + request.serverName + ':' + request.serverPort + request.forwardURI]">facebook</o:connect>
```

**NOTE:-** Use `request` as suggested by `@Burt Beckwith`. You cannot access `location` here.